# Using closures implement a private variable inside a class

Tags: javascript

Using closures implement a private variable inside a class such that it must be accessed via getter and setter functions.

Comment: I think you need to post some code of what you've done or tried.  This sounds pretty basic, much like jcubic's answer below, but perhaps you need something more.

Comment: Look like interview question or school assignment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this maybe:

```
function Something() {
   var foo = 'bar';
   this.getFoo = function() {
       return foo;
   };
   this.setFoo = function(newFoo) {
       foo = newFoo;
   };
}
var some = new Something();
some.setFoo('baz');
console.log(some.getFoo());
```